# Are "grouplike elements" in quasi-Hopf algebras still invertible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras, grouplike-elements

Suppose $H$ is a quasi-Hopf algebra with non-trivial evaluation $\alpha$. I cannot find any sources about grouplike elements in $H$. What I mean by "grouplike" is
$$ \Delta(g) = g\otimes g \quad\text{and}\quad\epsilon(g)=1 .$$
Obviously in a Hopf algebra this would imply $S(g)=g^{-1}$, but in quasi-Hopf we only get
$$ \alpha = S(g)\alpha g.$$

So, can we use some trick to deduce an answer to the question in the title, or is it in general only true for quasi-Hopf algebras with $\alpha =1$ (or invertible, ofc)?

---

(I tried cooking up a counterexample, but my qHA-Fu is still weak, and most examples are still terribly complicated to me)

Answer (score 1):

**Too long for a comment:**

Given a ordinary Hopf algebra $H$ the grouplike elements of $H$ correspond to the one-dimensional comodules of $H$. As the category of $H$-comodules is a monoidal category, the tensor product induces a group structure one the one-dimensional comodules. This group is isomorphic to $G(H)$.

A quasi-Hopf algebra $H$ is in general not an coassociative coalgebra and as such, comodules are not defined. From this perspective you don't expect grouplike elements (i.e. $\Delta(g)=g\otimes g$) to hold any important significance. There are some reasonable analogous of comodules over quasi-Hopf algebras in the literature, perhaps this is a good place to start.